Why doesn’t HTML in text (caption) of Label in AWT work?
I have a doubt can you use html tags in awt components like label or text components if you want to print it one after another.
Like example:
Label slabel = new Label("<html>line 1 <br>line 2</html>");

slabel.setBounds(22, 47, 248, 43);

slabel.setVisible(false);

add(slabel);

But it doesn't seem to work and is printing in one line along with the tags

From the Java documentation: "A label displays a single line of read-only text.". So no, you cannot have mutliple lines, and it does not handle HTML.

AWT components were superseded looooong ago. Unless you're being paid handsomely to maintain an ancient codebase as is, you're really wasting your time

Use Swing and JLabel, which does support basic HTML.
